# Missing one batch in the training for loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

- The data has `n_rows` rows
- The batch size is `batch_size`

I see some [code](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/51e53daaa2a32cfe7a1966f060b28dbbd081791c/examples/03_logreg_placeholder.py#L69) uses:

```
n_batches = int(n_rows / batch_size)
```

What if n_rows is not a multiple of batch size?
 Is the `n_batches` still correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can see that in several code, and we know that labeled data is extremely valuable so you don't want to loose some precious labeled examples. At first glance it looks like a bug, and it seems that we are loosing some training examples , but we have to get a closer look at the code.

When you see that, in general, as in the code that you sent, at each epoch (based on the fact that one epoch is seeing `n_batches = int(n_rows / batch_size)` examples), the data is **shuffled after each epoch**.  Therefore through time (after several epochs) you'll see **all** your training examples. We're not loosing any examples \o/

Small conclusion: If you see that, ensure that the data is shuffled at each epoch, otherwise your network might never see some training examples.

#### What are the advantages of doing that ?

*It's efficient*: 
By using this mechanism you ensure that at each **training step** your network will see **batch_size** examples, and you won't perform a training loop with a small number of training examples.

*It's more rigorous*: Imagine you have one example left and you don't shuffle. At each epoch , assuming your loss is the average loss of the batch, for this last example it will be equivalent to have a batch that consist of one element repeated `batch_size` time, it will be like weighting this example to have more importance. If you shuffle this effect will be reduced (since the remaining example will change through time), but it's more rigorous to have a constant batch size during your training epoch.

There are also some advantages of shuffling your data during training see:
[statexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/shuffling-data-in-the-mini-batch-training-of-neural-network/311318#311318)

I'll also add to the post, that if you are using mechanism such as Batch Normalization, it's better to have a constant batch size during training, for example if `n_rows % batch_size = 1` , passing a single example as batch **during training**  can create some troubles.

*Note:*
I speak about a constant batch size during a training epoch and not over the whole training cycle (multiple epochs) , because even if it's normally the case (to be constant during the whole training process), you can find some research work that modify the size of the batches during training e.g. [Don't Decay the Learning Rate, Increase the Batch Size](https://openreview.net/forum?id=B1Yy1BxCZ).

Comment: When I look at the behavior of `one_shot_iterator()`, I think the `n_batch` should actually be `n_rows // batch_size` only if `n_rows` is a multiple of `batch_size`. If `n_rows` is not a multiple of `batch_size`, then for every `1 + n_rows // batch_size` batches, the last one have less rows than other batches. I am using the same iterator to train multiple networks. The iterator yields shuffled data.

Comment: The iterator does not yield batches with a constant size if `n_rows` is not a multiple of `batch_size`. I can manually discard the last batch with a shorter size to make all batches have a constant size.

Comment: I guess , per default it avoid loosing some examples when you evaluate , but for training you can , shuffle + repeat + batch with drop remainder set to True ```batch(
    batch_size,
    drop_remainder=False
)
```